# How to check if application is running on background?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I am using firebase to send notifications to the application and based on the notification the user will be directed to some activity. so far so good, the problem I am having is that if the application is running on background the activity that will be shown is the main activity but I can not quite managed it to do it.

I believe there ar several questions like this, but do not quite get the answer I am looking for.

Any help or suggestion would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
/**Flag to determine if the Activity is visible*/
    private static boolean activityVisible;
    private static boolean activityDestroy;

/**Is the application actually visible on the mobile screen*/
public static boolean isActivityVisible(){
    return activityVisible;
}

/**Is the application actually destroyed*/
public static boolean isActivityDestroy(){
    return activityDestroy;
}

/**Is the application actually destroyed*/
public static void activityDestroy(boolean isDestroy){
    activityDestroy = isDestroy;
}

/**Is the application actually in the background*/
public static boolean isActivityInBackground(){
    return !activityVisible;
}


/**Change the state of the Application to resume*/
public static void activityResumed() {
    activityVisible = true;
}

/**Change the state of the Application to paused*/
public static void activityPaused() {
    activityVisible = false;
}
```

and then for checking

```
    Application app = ((Application)getApplicationContext());
    boolean visible = app.isActivityVisible();
```

Answer (score 0):

Android 10 (API level 29) and higher place restrictions on when apps can start activities when the app is running in the background. These restrictions help minimize interruptions for the user and keep the user more in control of what's shown on their screen.

Comment: thanks for the reply. what restrictions would that be?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [importance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo#importance) field of [ActivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager).
Below the method for Xamarin using by C#, but it's pretty similiar to Java.

P.S.: If you want I could port that code to Java

```
    public static Importance GetAppState(Context context, string packageName)
    {
        try
        {
            var manager = (ActivityManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);

            var processes = manager.RunningAppProcesses;

            if (processes != null)
                foreach (var process in processes)
                    if (process.ProcessName.Equals(packageName))
                        return process.Importance;
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return Importance.Gone;
    }
```